# need to account for params being blank in node express app

Tags: node.js, express, validation

i have a node/express app, and need to account for if users don't enter a `stationId` param in the Url. Ive been looking at all sorts of regex built in to express, adding express-validator but couldnt get it to work for middleware. what would be the best way to do this? is the something in express or a third party validator?

The stationId is an mix of letters and numbers `1491TH` it is used to call a second API to get information about the station entered in the Url. Im trying to work out how to use a validator to check if the param is blank, or if its not in the format i want.

```
import express from 'express'
import axios from 'axios'
import { cleanseLocation } from './utils.js'


const PORT = 3000
const app = express()

app.get('/:stationId/asset',(req, res) => {

 const stationId = cleanseLocation(req.params.stationId)

 const resp = await axios.get(`https://online-api/id/stations/${stationId}`)
   res.send(resp)
})

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`The node API is running on: http://localhost:${PORT}.`)
)
```

Comment: How do you know if some sequence of characters is a valid `stationId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a route like:

```
app.get('/:stationId/asset', ...)
```

You are using a wildcard for the first path segment.  It will match ANYTHING in the first path segment.  So, it will match all of these:

```
/play/asset
/1238576/asset
/%20/asset
```

It will not match:

```
/asset
```

because that's just one path segment.

If you have specific rules for what is and isn't a valid stationId, you can implement a check for those inside the route handler:

```
app.get('/:stationId/asset',(req, res) => {
   if (some logic to check req.param.stationId) {
       res.send('working');
   } else {
       res.status(404).send("Invalid stationId");
   }
});
```

If you need further help with how to implement `stationId` checking, you will have to disclose exactly how you would tell if it's a valid `stationId` or not.

> is the something in express or a third party validator?

What mechanism to use for implementing validation depends entirely upon how you determine whether it is or isn't a valid `stationId`.  You would have to explain that algorithm or method for us to help further.

> The stationId is an mix of letters and numbers 1491TH it is used to call a second API to get information about the station entered in the Url. Im trying to work out how to use a validator to check if the param is blank, or if its not in the format i want

It already can't be blank.  It won't match the route if there's no `stationId` at all.

So, if you are looking for a sequence of letters and numbers, you can just use a regex and define the route such that it will only match the route definition if you get a legal format for a stationId:

```
app.get('/:stationId([A-Za-z0-9]+)/asset', ...)
```

FYI, here's a [helpful article](https://www.kevinleary.net/regex-route-express/) with good example on using regex in Express routes.  The full doc for what you can do with a regex in a route definition is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) in the `path-to-regexp` documentation which is the module Express uses for this feature.

Comment: sorry ill edit the question, thank you for replying

Comment: It will also not match `//asset` (`stationId` empty), which I think is that OP was expecting (in their initial, now deleted, question, they tried to ensure that `stationId` wasn't empty using `express-validator`, but it was attached to a route trying to match `/:stationId/asset`, which doesn't get called when it's empty).

Comment: @wycherley22 - It already can't be blank because it won't match the route if the stationId is blank.  That would be an invalid URL too as in `http://somehost//asset`.  I've added a regex to my answer that will match just letters and numbers (basically avoiding punctuation and other special characters) in the `stationId` position of the URL.

Comment: ill add the regex, thank you for your help